# How can I know whether the user's email is verified in Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

How can I know whether the user's email is verified in Firebase Console? The users were sent emails to verify their emails, but some users didn't activate them. When I look in Firebase Console, I don't see the difference between who verified their emails and who did not. So I need to know who verified their email and who did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to see if a user's email address has been verified in the Firebase console. You will have to write code for that, using the Admin SDK to [get the user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) or a [list of all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).

Comment: From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup): "The Admin SDK lets you interact with Firebase from privileged environments to perform [privileged] actions". I recommend reading more about it there and seeing if it fits your needs.